# Template engine for a YAML file in Java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, templates

I am looking for ways in which we can have a common template for YAML documents and be able to dynamically populate the values in the yaml files in Java spring boot.

So under resources in spring boot, will create a folder for templates, under which we will have a YAML file. This yaml file should be referenced in the Java helper class, dynamically populate the values, convert this yaml doc to a escape string and pass it as a parameter.

Came accross templates like thymeleaf/ pebble but these are not very efficient for the required use case.

Would appreciate any suggestions on this.